# Is there a MultiBody equivalent of PostureChangeConstraint?

Tags: drake

I am trying to constrain the solution to be within a max angular distance for each joint, and I think with RigidBodyTree, I could just add a `PostureChangeConstraint`, but is there an equivalent for MultiBody tree? Other than perhaps using angle between vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add that constraint through `MathematicalProgram::AddLinearConstraint`. For example, say you have a trajectory optimization problem `prog`, and you want to constraint that the difference between `q[n+1]` and `q[n]` are less than a bound `max_delta_q`. You could do it as

```cpp
nq = plant.num_positions();
A = Eigen::MatrixXd(nq, 2*nq);
A << Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(nq), -Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(nq)
// Add the constraint -max_delta_q <= q[n+1] - q[n] <= max_delta_q
prog.AddLinearConstraint(A, -max_delta_q, max_delta_q, {q[n], q[n+1]});
```